# Preventing git push from sending entire repo if not up-to-date

Tags: git, continuous-integration, msysgit, gitosis, git-push

**Related question: [why does Git send whole repository each time push origin master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381403/why-does-git-send-whole-repository-each-time-push-origin-master)**

**The short version:** When working with two Git repositories, even if 99% of the commit objects are identical, using `git push` to send a commit to repository *B* when `origin` is set to point to repo *A* causes all objects (200MB +) to be transferred.

**The much longer version:** We have a second Git repository set up on our continuous integration server. After we have prepared our commit objects locally, instead of pushing directly to `origin/master` as one normally would, we instead push our changes to a branch on this second repository. The CI server picks up the new branch, auto-rebases it onto `master`, runs our integration tests and, if all is well, pushes the branch to `origin/master` on the master repo.

The CI server also periodically calls `git fetch` to retrieve the latest copy of `origin/master` from the master repo, in case someone has gone around the CI process and pushed directly.

This works wonderfully, especially if one does a `git fetch; git rebase origin/master` before pushing to the CI repo; Git only sends the commit objects that are not already in `origin/master`. If one skips the fetch/rebase step before pushing, the process still works, but Git appears to send, if not all, then a majority of commit objects to the CI repo -- currently more than 200MB worth. (A fresh clone of our repo clocks in at 225MB.)

Are we doing something wrong? Is there a way to correct this behaviour such that Git only sends the commit objects it needs to form the branch on the CI repo? We can obviously work around the issue by doing a pre-push `git fetch; git rebase origin/master`, but it feels like we should be able to skip that step, especially because pushing directly to the master repo does not present the same problem.

Our repos are served up by Gitosis 0.2, and our clients are overwhelmingly running msysgit 1.7.3.1-preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the simplest solution to this problem *is* to fetch right before the push:

```
$ git fetch origin master
$ git push user@host:repo.git HEAD:refs/heads/commit128952690069
```

In our case, it's important to fetch a specific branch into `FETCH_HEAD`; in this way, the user's local branch state will be *unaffected*, but we still receive the most up-to-date set of objects from the main repository; the following `git push` will always have the ancestor commit present when the Git starts to pack objects.

I did some tooling around with `git pack-objects`: if one builds a pack file containing the commits `<common_ancestor>..HEAD`, it only packs as much data as is required:

```
$ echo $(git merge-base master origin/master)..HEAD | git pack-objects --revs --thin --stdout --all-progress-implied > packfile
```

However, issuing `git push` with the repository in the same state causes *all* objects to get packed and sent.

I suspect what happens is that upon connecting to the Git repo, one receives the SHA of the latest revision in the repo -- if Git does not have the commit object represented by that SHA locally, it cannot run `git merge-base` to determine the common ancestor; therefore, it must send all the objects to the remote repo. If that commit object does exist, then `git merge-base` succeeds, and the pack file can be built referencing the common ancestor.

Comment: This worked for me too, but I still find it mysterious.

Answer (score 2):

> *...auto-rebases it onto `master`...*

I think that is the root of the problem right there. Every time your CI server does this auto-rebase step, it will create a whole *new* set of commits relative to the nearest common ancestor of the current and the master branch.

The next time you push your code to the CI server, it doesn't actually have all those object anymore (they're not reachable from any live heads), so it requests your client to send them all again.

You should be able to see this happening by watching the SHA1 commit IDs of the commits you're making. You will probably find that the commit IDs of local commits no longer match the corresponding commit IDs in the rebased branch on the CI server.

Comment: Yes, the commit SHAs will change when the rebase occurs on the CI server, however, that should *not* cause the *entire repository* to be re-sent; one of the rules of using Git is "don't rewrite commits that are already in `master`" -- we haven't broken this rule. At most, I would have expected that commits down to a common ancestor would be sent.

Comment: Also, we've checked the SHAs on both repositories for our commits, and they do match.

Comment: One approach you could try is to use `git push --dry-run --verbose` and see whether you can determine which objects are being sent.

Comment: running with `--dry-run --verbose` does not give any information about which objects would be sent, just that the push would create a new remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your local repositories got out of sync with the CI server repository, the fact that a push from you to the CI server does this means that your local repository has a different set of commit hashes.  It could go something like this:

```
git clone master
(... do work ...)
git push ci branch
(... CI does a rebase that changes all the commits hashes you pushed ..)
(... CI does its' testing and pushes to master ...)
(... Now master and CI match but the hashes of all the commits you just pushed
     don't exist anywhere except your local machine ...)
(... do work ...)
git push ci branch
```

That last push is going to contain the entire set of commits from your first push because the CI's rebase changed all of their hashes and you're still working off the original commits that you created.

Comment: But they won't have an *entirely* different set of hashes, right? The local, master and CI repos should have a common ancestor commit that has the same SHA on all machines; Git demands it, or merging/rebasing would fall apart. Is there a way to hint to Git what that ancestor might be? It simply appears to be choosing it incorrectly.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't clear when I said entirely I've edited my answer to clarify.  The rebase will change everything back to the common ancestor.  The problem with the workflow you're talking about is that if this happens every time you push to CI (which doesn't seem that unlikely if a bunch of other people are also pushing) then that common ancestor may well be the commit that was current when you cloned the repository the first time.

Comment: A way to test if this is the problem would be to clone master again and see if a push from that does the same thing. If this is what is happening then a push from a new clone won't do this. A new clone won't exhibit the problem immediately because the difference in history isn't as great.  It will get progressively worse over time unless you change what the CI does.