# How to view the file size before I commit with git?

Tags: git, github

I want to commit some files to GitHub, and I have created one ignore file, but how do I view the file size before committing?

Comment: Do you mean the real file size or the actual amount of data that is going to be transmitted?

Comment: the actual amount of data that is going to be transmitted to github

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a note on terminology - you record changes in a new "commit" locally (with `git commit`) and then would "push" your changes to GitHub.  You only push commits, not particular files.

You've clarified in a comment that what you're after is the amount of data that would be uploaded when you do `git push`, in which case [Jefromi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179842/predict-how-much-data-will-be-pushed-in-a-git-push/4181602#4181602) to the question [Predict how much data will be pushed in a git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179842/predict-how-much-data-will-be-pushed-in-a-git-push) should help you.

Comment: Blair's answer to that question is also excellent, just not quite as porcelain-y.