# delete large file git commit

Tags: git, github

I committed several large files and I got this error

```
gabbo@gabbo-SATELLITE-L750:/media/Data/Condiviso/TUe/Smartscope_study/smartscope_code$ git add -A
gabbo@gabbo-SATELLITE-L750:/media/Data/Condiviso/TUe/Smartscope_study/smartscope_code$ git commit -m "test"
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
gabbo@gabbo-SATELLITE-L750:/media/Data/Condiviso/TUe/Smartscope_study/smartscope_code$ git push origin master
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-iLiKTe/pkcs11: No such file or directory
Username for 'https://github.com': gabboshow
Password for 'https://gabboshow@github.com': 
remote: warning: File DATA/segmentation/Feat_2.mat is 94.46 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: warning: File DATA/segmentation/Feat_3.mat is 61.77 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: warning: File DATA/segmentation/Feat_4.mat is 80.35 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: warning: File DATA/segmentation/Feat_5.mat is 85.85 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: warning: File DATA/segmentation/Feat_6.mat is 78.94 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: warning: File DATA/segmentation/Feat_7.mat is 66.61 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: 66ef415089784516b0d76ac2e639a7ac
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File DATA/segmentation/Feat_1.mat is 123.29 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB
To https://github.com/gabboshow/smartscope_code.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/gabboshow/smartscope_code.git'
gabbo@gabbo-SATELLITE-L750:/media/Data/Condiviso/TUe/Smartscope_study/smartscope_code$
```

after that I messed up with others

```
git add -A
git commit -m "xxx" 
git push origin master
```

I identified the files that cause problems. They are listed in a file called /large_files.txt in my git repository.

```
129281677 DATA/segmentation/Feat_1.mat
99053081 DATA/segmentation/Feat_2.mat
90017465 DATA/segmentation/Feat_5.mat
84251508 DATA/segmentation/Feat_4.mat
82775151 DATA/segmentation/Feat_6.mat
69845263 DATA/segmentation/Feat_7.mat
64768848 DATA/segmentation/Feat_3.mat
```

How can I proceed to delete the wrong commits and push a clean version of my repository?

Comment: You can reset your branch with --hard option to the point where files were not commited or you can do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589167/my-git-push-is-stuck-on-a-large-file-what-to-do/23589297?noredirect=1#comment36275004_23589297 . Either way after you clean your local repo you can overwrite the remote branch with push -f or --force option (not every remote will allow you to do that it depends on the configuration). But from the error you've pasted it seems like your push has been declined so you probably only need to fix your branch locally.

Comment: Hi,
I used the comment git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf DATA/*' HEAD and now I have in my repository a very old version of my code... could you please help me?? a bit desperate...

Comment: First see if you have actually pushed your changes to remote `git checkout -b whatever_name_you_like origin/master` and check the history. if it's ok then just delete your local branch and create a new one from origin/master.

Comment: can you tell me please how to do that? I'm new to git...anyway I'm pretty sure that I pushed after having used git-filter-branch.

Comment: To recap I tried to push large files, I continued working on my code, I used git-filter-branch as written above and pushed, I figured out that my code was an old copy. In the git repository I miss the part between the last correct push (before trying to push the large file) and the last one..

Comment: well you didn't tell thet you made some changes to code after failed push in your original question. anyway run `git log` and see if you have all your commits

Comment: yes the problem is that they jump from the one where I had the code to an old version to the one of today. In the middle I modified the code locally but I couldn t push because I was trying to push large files

Comment: Since you've failed to push large file you also failed to push commit after that. The question is do you have all your changes locally?

Comment: the weird thing is this...I thought that git didn't touch my files locally but apparently it did...I mean I did it following some commands in some tutorial like $git commit --amend -CHEAD or $git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm -rf NAME/FOLDER' HEAD

Comment: I will try once again. If your last commit message was "xxx" does `git log -1` returns commit with the 'xxx' message?

Comment: yes, it returns exactly my last message, but before I think I touched something (I really don't know what) that modified my local rep.

Comment: ok. run `git status` and tell me what it returned

Comment: # On branch checking
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
(thanks for your help btw)

Comment: If it's not clear what I did is
1) I pushed the last time on May the 9th
2) I modified locally the code
3) I tried to push large files so git didn't allow me
4) I did some mess trying to cancel the commits
5) I pushed again today and I found both locally and in the rep the code at the last correct push (point 1)

Comment: run 'git checkout master`. do you have your code now?

Comment: No I have always the code at the commit before the changes..

Comment: That's not good. did your reset with --hard option at some point? run `git reflog'. do you see your not pushed commit that you think you have lost?

Comment: No, I've never used the option --hard, but I don't see my not pushed commit...though I think I used several times the same commit message until it worked

Comment: here I tried to list the commands that I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627522/recover-git-repository-to-old-version

Comment: Well the things you've listed wouldn't mess with your code (but please  note that in your second command you delete some other folder) so you had to do something wrong before that. you can try `git checkout refs/original/refs/heads/master` and if you succeed check what code you have there. I don't really know there is much more you can do but maybe somebody else will know how to help you. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> "remote: error: File DATA/segmentation/Feat_1.mat is 123.29 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB"

Your file `DATA/segmentation/Feat_1.mat` exceeds GitHub's [maximum file size](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota) of 100MB and is therefore revoked. As what can be read from your questions, you have no "wrong" commits. You just failed at pushing to GitHub.

You may remove at least this too big file and commit the change. After that you'll be able to push to GitHub again.

If you must version control these large files i suggest you reading the help article on [Working with large files](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files).

If you want to keep these files in your project folder i recommend you to ignore them from now on:

#### Ignoring already tracked files

Add 'DATA/segmentation/*.mat' to your [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) (there's also a good [help-resource on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) about that topic).

After that remove these tracked files from your repository using:

```
git rm --cached DATA/segmentation/*.mat
```

Which untracks the files and makes them now unknown to git.