# recover git repository to old version

Tags: git, repository

I had quite some problems after pushing large files in the git reposotory.

I tried different things messing up everything.

The last command I tried was

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter -f 'rm -rf FOLDERWITHLARGEFILES/*' HEAD
```

and it I thought I solved the problem because the following

```
git push origin master
```

worked.

The problem is that now I have a very old version of my rep. I think that is the version before I tried to commit the large files. Is there a way to recover the repository.

To recap:

I tried to push large files.
I continued working on my files
I tried to solve the problem of pushing large files...

Thanks a lot in advance

Here the history of what I did:

```
1) I pushed the last time on May the 9th
2) I modified locally the code
3) I tried to push large files so git didn't allow me
4) I did some mess trying to cancel the commits like:
     $ git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm -rf FOLDERWITHLARGEFILES/*' HEAD
     $ git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch DATA/*' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
     $ git commit --amend -CHEAD
     $ git rm --cached FOLDERWITHLARGEFILES/
     $ git update-index --assume-unchanged FOLDERWITHLARGEFILES/
5) I pushed again today and I found both locally and in the rep the code at the last correct push (point 1)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *recover*? What would you like to do?

Comment: I edited my question..I hope it's more clear and that you can help me